# Tomcat LDAP JNDI configuration role search

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap, jndi, apacheds

I'm looking for a way to refine my role management using Apache DS with Tomcat and an LDAP realm JNDI setup via a `context.xml` file.  I'm not that proficient in these topics so please excuse any glaring terminology mistakes I make.

#### Context.xml

My current `context.xml` file is as such

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
     connectionName="uid=admin,ou=system"
     connectionPassword="PASSWORD"
     roleBase="ou=Groups,dc=ff,dc=local"
     roleName="cn"
     roleNested="true"
     roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"
     roleSubtree="true"
     userBase="ou=People,dc=ff,dc=local"
     userSearch="(mail={0})"
     connectionURL="${ldapServer}"
  />
```

The way I understand it is as follows:

- `connectionName`, `connectionPassword`, and `connectionURL` setup the credentials to log into ApacheDS
- `userBase` sets the search path for users
- `userSearch="(mail={0})"` means that it is going to search for users in `ou=People,dc=ff,dc=local` where there is an entry with `mail` equal to the search key (in our case a login email)

For example I have an entry called:

```
cn=A52Q7BBN9PVHHPH
sn=User
givenName=Test
mail=testUser@test.com
userPassword=SSHA-512 hashed password
... (some other non importnat fileds)
```

So my understanding is that if we login to the web server with `testUser@test.com` tomcat is going to do a query for `cn` where the attribute `mail=testUser@test.com`

This works great but where I'm running into issues is figuring out an easier way to do role management

#### Roles

I have an "entry?" called `cn=ff-admin` in `ou=Groups`, and as i understand any "entry" in this group is supposed to indicate a user with admin privileges.  The problem is that the entries look like:

`uniqueMember=cn=A52Q7BBN9PVHHPH,ou=People,dc=ff,dc=local`

as opposed to something more readable like perhaps this:

`uniqueMember=mail=testUser@test.com`

I'm searching a way to modify my `context.xml` to make it easier to do user management via LDAP so that I do not have to attempt to cross reference a random `cn` to an actual email address.

I'm assuming i could change the `roleSearch=....` entry but I wanted to reach out to the stack community before i started hacking away and possibly broke something.

```
roleBase="ou=Groups,dc=ff,dc=local"
roleName="cn"
roleNested="true"
roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"
roleSubtree="true"
```